# Есть ли казахстанский русский язык?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Можно ли русский язык в Казахстане назвать другим вариантом русского языка?

Comment: Наряду с какими?

Comment: допустим в английском есть американский, британский и прочие акценты, и мне стало интересно. просто как-то странно выглядит что есть где в другом государстве (РФ) организация которая публикует нормы русского языка.

Answer (score 2):

Русский язык в Казахстане как и СНГ является одним из официальных и рабочих языков ООН, ЮНЕСКО и т.д., входит в клуб «мировых языков» и де-факто является распространенным средством межэтнического и делового общения в этой стране, оставаясь русским, но преимущественно литературным и казённым, языком. Подробнее — в небольшом реферате: http://www.refsru.com/referat-6661-17.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Также как можно назвать другим вариантом языка вологодский, тверской и пр. русский. В той или иной степени диалектные особенности есть почти во всех регионах распространения русского языка. Другое дело, что литературной нормой всё равно является московское или петербуржское произношение, а остальное это уже отклонение от неё.

Comment: «Литературной нормой является... произношение»?

Comment: @shampar Ну да. Московское и питерское - произносительная литературная норма. Можно это точнее сформулировать, но суть вполне отражает.

Comment: Вопрос о языке. Произношение и его норма — не главная его составляющая. В конце концов это обёртка.